# Unable to submit infopath 2010 form - Issue with just one user

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, infopath-data-connections

We have a infopath for that submits data to a form library. The form works just fine for all the team members but one user is unable to submit the same.

The root cause of this issue is that the form's data connection to the library looks like this:

```
http://examplesite.com/sites/my%20list%20name
```

Upon changing the %20 encoding and replacing with space like below

```
http://examplesite.com/sites/my list name
```

and publishing the same resolves the issue for the user and all other users are also able to work on this with no issues.

We think this might be something to do with url encoding and settings on the Internet Explorer. Any pointers on this issue will be really helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please try using without space..!!! change both the list name and the url,

Answer (score 0):

Does the infopath form contain lookup fields?
If it does, make sure this user also has access to the list where the lookup refers to.